# How do I add or remove class from HTML tag (using toggle) in React.js

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Dear StackOverflow users. I need to make a dark mode using React.js and Tailwind, but when my dark mode icon is clicked, I need to add and remove the dark class from the HTML tag (in a toggle), but I am getting an error.

**Code**

```
const [isDark, setDark] = useState(false)
    const toggleDark = () => {
        setDark(!isDark)
       const html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")
        console.log(html);
        html.classList.toggle("dark")
    }

<span id='darkmode' className='w-5 h-5 bg-white block 
    cursor-pointer' onClick={toggleDark}></span>
```

**Error**

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggle')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName("html")` actually returns an array. `classList` is not a property of an array, so it becomes undefined. In order to actually toggle it, get the first item of the array, which will be the html element.

```js
const html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :
<span id='darkmode' className={`w-5 h-5 bg-white block cursor-pointer ${isDark ? dark : ''}`} onClick={toggleDark}>

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. The element I need to give the dark class is the element named html. <html>